# How to use ic_ab_back_holo_light icon on both Android 4 and 5?

Tags: android, icons, nativescript

[In this page](http://androiddrawables.com/Other.html) I want to use `ic_ab_back_holo_light` for both android 4 and 5. However, that icon is not available for Android 4.4+. For android 4.4+, same icon is available as `ic_ab_back_holo_light_am`. How can I use this icon on both Android 4 and 5?

I will this icon in ActionBar and it is not possible to put icons and fonts in ActionBar icons. Only system icons are allowed as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should be better than an image https://www.nativescript.org/blog/details/mobile-app-best-practices---use-font-instead-of-image-to-show-an-icon

Comment: Forgot to mention: I will use the icon in ActionBar buttons. Fonts and images are not allowed.

Comment: if you are not using actionItem you can create a custom action bar like so <ActionBar.titleView> Layout buttons etc</ActionBar.titleView>